# Cordova blackberry requierments check failed while adding new platform

Tags: cordova, ant, blackberry

I just installed node.js with cordova. Everything works fine, but when  I want to add the BlackBerry10 platform it just says: Requierments check failed: and no error message. 
Phonegap won't install either. I have no idea what is going on. Ant is correctly installed, my PATH is set correctly (at least it seems like; followed the instructions). And it still won't work. Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Did you install the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK?

Comment: Yes i have the WebWorks SDK 1.0.4 and the newest momentics! should i try webworks 2.1?

Comment: Just tried with the new sdk still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Windows completly it finally works! I know wasn't the best way - but I'm very happy that it works!